# What is the optimal way to get selected elements from a matrix?

Tags: matrix, parallelization

I have a 2x2 matrix "M", and a list "ind" containing pairs of indices.

```
M = {{a, b, c}, {d, f, g}, {h, i, j}};
ind = {{1, 2}, {1, 1}, {3, 1}};
```

I would like to get the elements of the matrix given by the indices in "ind", in this case:

```
{b,a,h}
```

The only way I've found to do this is with MapThread:

```
MapThread[M[[#1, #2]] &, ind\[Transpose]]
```

However, the matrices and lists I am using are quite large, and this takes considerable time.
Is there a more efficient way to do this?
Can this be parallelized (maybe by using ParallelMap, instead of MapThread)?

Comment: `M[[Sequence @@ #]] & /@ ind` and Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange.

Comment: This is better than MapThread, thank you @Syed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way is the following

```
M = {{a, b, c}, {d, f, g}, {h, i, j}};
ind = {{1, 2}, {1, 1}, {3, 1}};
```

Now

```
 Extract[M, ind]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Look up [Extract](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Extract.html)

Also `Position` is designed to return index location which can be used by `Extract` which makes it easy. You can use `Position` and then pass the result directly to `Extract` without having to worry if it will work or not and this works for lists of different dimensions.

> The position specifications used by Extract have the same form as
> those returned by Position, and used in functions such as MapAt and
> ReplacePart. »

Comment: `Extract` is noticeably better than `MapThread`, thank you.